# PHP - Could this if statement EVER return true?

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to edit my co-worker's code (he's on vacation and out of reach) and there is this if statement:

```
if($this->carrier() == 1 and $this->carrier() == 2) {
    return 'V';
}
```

My hope is that he accidentally put "and" instead of "or" which could explain a bug I'm getting, but he knows much more about PHP than I do and I want to be sure that this is wrong instead of just counter intuitive.

Comment: Yes it can, if `$this->carrier()` returns different values per call. But if it does not, then no. So whether this statement is a mistake depends on what `$this->carrier()` is doing.

Comment: Yesit can as everybody saying, But, it should not be implemented this way. I suggest switching to OR and see if it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, since it's a function with potential side effects, it might be true.

For example:

```
function carrier() {
    return $someValue++;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The `carrier()` method could increment whatever value it returns each time you call it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a small chance it could, yes.

He's calling a function twice, and you've not included the text of that function. So that could be doing something we can't see, like counting the number of times it's been called by this process.

On the other hand, it's much more likely that it is indeed a typo.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Here is a working example you can run.

```
class program
{
private $i = 1;
function carrier()
{
 $this->i=$this->i+1;
 return $this->i-1;
}

function run()
{
 if ($this->carrier()==1 && $this->carrier()==2)
 {
  echo "works";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "doesnt work" . $i;
 }
}
}

$prog = new Program();
$prog->run();
```